Обработка видео в несколько этапов, используя Python
стоит задача:

Есть видео mp4, вес 500Мб, кодек h264, скаченное с телеграмм
Надо это видео разрезать на две части, первая часть 2 секунды, вторая остаток
Наложить на 5 кадр первой части видео текст и потом соединить первую и вторую части
Все это должно сделаться на Питоне максимум за 1:30-2:00 минуты

Что получилось у меня:

Видео разрезал
Текст на первую часть наложил
Соединяю и получаю не корректную длину видео

Что я заметил:

Когда я разрезаю видео на две части и соединяю их обратно - все соединяется отлично, без косяков и т.п
Как только я наложил текст на первую часть видео и пытаюсь соединить со второй частью - получаю не корректную длину итогового видео.
Программа меня так же предупреждает о том, что dps < tps. Я проверил метаданные времени первой части видео с наложенным текстом и получил что dps иногда имеет значение меньше, чем tps, я проверил первую часть видео без текста, там все идет идеально, как надо. Видимо в этом причина не корректной длины итогового видео.

Прикладываю свой код:
 # Команда для сохранения отрезанной части
command_save_cut_part = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-ss",
    "00:00:00",  # Начальное время отрезанной части
    "-i",
    "record.mp4",
    "-t",
    "00:00:10",  # Продолжительность отрезанной части
    "-c:v",
    "copy",
    "-c:a",
    "copy",
    f"1.mp4"
]

# Выполнение команды для сохранения отрезанной части
subprocess.run(command_save_cut_part)

# Команда для сохранения оставшейся части видео
command_save_remaining_part = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-ss",
    "00:00:10",  # Начальное время оставшейся части (после отрезанной части)
    "-i",
    "record.mp4",
    "-c:v",
    "copy",
    "-c:a",
    "copy",
    f"{video_dir}/2.mp4"
]

# Выполнение команды для сохранения оставшейся части
subprocess.run(command_save_remaining_part)

# Пути к файлам
video_path = f"1.mp4"
frame_path = f"frame.png"
frame_with_text_path = f"frame_with_text.png"

# Параметры текста
text = str(123456789)
x_position = 5
y_position = 5
font_size = 8
font_color = "white"  # Цвет текста белый

# Команда для извлечения пятого кадра
command_extract_frame = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    video_path,
    "-vf",
    "select=gte(n\,4)",
    "-vframes",
    "1",
    frame_path
]

# Выполнение команды для извлечения кадра
subprocess.run(command_extract_frame)

# Команда для наложения текста на кадр
command_overlay_text = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    frame_path,
    "-vf",
    f"drawtext=text='{text}':x={x_position}:y={y_position}:fontsize={font_size}:fontcolor={font_color}",
    frame_with_text_path
]

# Выполнение команды для наложения текста
subprocess.run(command_overlay_text)

# Команда для замены пятого кадра на кадр с текстом
command_replace_frame = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    video_path,
    "-i",
    frame_with_text_path,
    "-filter_complex",
    "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='eq(n,4)'",
    "-codec:a",
    "copy",
    f"1_2.mp4"
]

# Выполнение команды для замены кадра в видео
subprocess.run(command_replace_frame)

# Удаление временных файлов
os.remove(frame_path)
os.remove(frame_with_text_path)

video_out_path = f'здесь мой путь'
success_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(video_out_path), "list.txt")
with open(success_file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write(f"file '1_2.mp4'\n"
               f"file '2.mp4'\n")

output_video_path = f"total.mp4"

# Коррекция команды для объединения видео
command = [
'ffmpeg',
'-f', 'concat',
'-safe', '0',
'-i', 'list.txt',
'-c', 'copy',
'output_2.mp4'
]

# Выполнение команды для объединения видео
subprocess.run(command)

Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей и есть другие, быстрые варианты? Или может я делаю что-то не так?
